# The complexification of Hodge class is properly contained in the space of type $V^{k,k}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory, k3-surfaces

I was reading Professor Huybrechts's Lectures on K3 surfaces, there is a statement about Hodge class that I can't figure out.

Let's consider the (integral or rational) Hodge structure $V$ with the Hodge decomposition $$V_{\mathbb{C}} = \bigoplus_{p+q = n}V^{p,q}$$we define the Hodge class to be $\text{Hdg}^{2k}(V) = V\cap V^{k,k}$, the book says in general we have proper inclusion $$(V\cap V^{k,k})_{\mathbb{C}} \subset V^{k,k}$$however $(V_{\mathbb{R}}\cap  V^{k,k})_{\mathbb{C}} = V^{k,k}$. I found it confusing, why is there a difference here?

(I found a post https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4192210/360262 which shows it is related to the complex version of Hodge conjecture)

The question is How can I prove that $(V_{\mathbb{R}}\cap  V^{k,k})_{\mathbb{C}} = V^{k,k}$ why it does not apply to $\mathbb{Q}$-coefficient? (I guess it's related to the conjugation, but don't know how to write it down clearly?)

Comment: Ok I see I will write the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(An elementary proof, I guess there may have more advanced proof.)

First, an element $\alpha =\sum \alpha^{p,q} \in V_\mathbb{C}$ lies in $V_{\mathbb{R}}\cap V^{k,k}$ iff $\alpha = \alpha^{k,k}$ such that $\bar{\alpha}^{k,k} = \alpha^{k,k}$.

On the other hand pick an arbitrary element $\alpha \in V^{k,k}$ then since the Hodge type $(k,k)$ is stable under conjugation we have $\bar{\alpha} \in V^{k,k}$ thus $\alpha + \bar{\alpha} \in (V_{\mathbb{R}}\cap V^{k,k})$. Similarily we have $\sqrt{-1}(\alpha -\bar{\alpha}) \in (V_{\mathbb{R}}\cap V^{k,k})$ thus taking complexification we have $$\alpha = 1/2\cdot ((\alpha + \bar{\alpha})- (\sqrt{-1})(\sqrt{-1}(\alpha -\bar{\alpha})) \in (V_{\mathbb{R}}\cap V^{k,k})_{\mathbb{C}}$$

which shows $(V_{\mathbb{R}}\cap V^{k,k})_{\mathbb{C}} = V^{k,k}$.

On the other hand, we have for rational Hodge structure, there is no such action as conjugation to preserve it.